# Who is Krishna? Is it Draupadi or an avatar of Vishnu?

Tags: krishna, name, draupadi

I am confused with the name Krishna. As per my current knowledge, then name of the the Ninth Avatar(birth) of Narayan is Krishan/krishn (not krishna). And Krishna is the name of Draupadi. But we often use word Krishna as Lord Vishnu's avatar.

I think this confusion is because of English language. In English laguage we often messes up Lord's name by putting "a" at the end of the name like we type Ram as Rama, Ramayan as Ramayana etc. And same way we type Krishan/krishn as Krishna.

But the question is whether Lord Narayan Avatar also has same name as Draupadi had because we often use word Krishna for Lord Narayan even when we talk in Hindi OR Krishna is only name of Draupadi, not of Narayan. Is name Krishna is being used in any of our scriptures as Lord Narayan's Avatar name?

Comment: Lord is कृष्ण (Krishna), Draupadi is कृष्णा (Krishnã)

Comment: Look at this: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/spelling-non-english-words-in-english-search-results

Comment: @Tezz Then why people often use Krishna instead of Krishan? And why the tag I have put in my question, it's spelling is Krishna, not Krishan or Krishn?

Comment: putting 'a' at end of name, like Rama, is common in South India, whereas saying just Ram is common in North India. 'Rama' or 'Krishna' is also 8th vibhakthi (sambodhan) in sanskrit, when you call someone's name, you say 'Hey Rama, come here', or 'Krishna, where are you'. That's why most people say Rama or Krishna instead of Ram or Krishn. Whereas, just 'Ram' (राम्) is not technically correct, it should be 'Ramaha, or Ram:' (राम:) or 'Krishnaha or Krishna:' (कृष्ण:) with visarga at end.

Comment: @ram But I think more correct spelling in English for Krishna would be Krishn because it matches exact Hindi name. And also, it (Krishn) doesn't change our pronunciation.

Comment: Sanskrit is the original, Hindi is Sanskrit mixed with Urdu which is muslim/mleccha bhasha. In Sanskrit, it is कृष्ण: (Krishnaha), not Krishn (which has halank at end and doesn't mean anything)

Comment: @Tezz, actually, it is कृष्ण: , not just कृष्ण .. there is visarga at end, but colloquially we drop it and just say Krishna not Krishn or Krishnaha

Comment: @Rishabh Sanskrit is language of Attributes. People are named after qualities. Krishna is called कृष्ण  as he is black (Narayana is Megha varnam). Shiva means auspicious. Vishnum means "all pervading". So, as Parabrahman has infinite attributes, he is called by infinite names. There are no proper nouns in Sanskrit or Veda Bhasha to be precise. This also makes Sanskrit eternal language (and so vedas). See [these introduction lessons](http://www.hitxp.com/articles/sanskrit-lessons/).

Comment: If it's written in English then we have to derive from the context. But if it's written in Hindi then कृष्णा means Draupadi and कृष्ण means Lord Shri Krishna or Arjun.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Hindi versions of these Sanskrit epithets drop the final vowel.

Comment: Please use capital letters in a word when the respective letter is pronounced at high pitch. For example कृष्णः should be written as krishnaH and for कृष्णा it should be written as krishnA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct pronunciation of name in Sanskrit = कृष्ण: or Krishnaha , राम: or Raamaha , 
because in Sanskrit grammar, that is the first vibhakthi.

The last 8th vibhakthi allows for saying Krishna (कृष्ण) or Raama (राम) when calling the person.
**Note** - this is not Krishnaa (कृष्णा) or Raamaa (रामा), which is not technically correct male name. But when calling someone, they might elongate the 'aa' at the end, and that is fine.

कृष्णा or Krishnaa is correct female name, and it denotes Draupadi. She was black in complexion, and so was Krishna, hence the name.

Btw, due to slight cultural variations in language, North Indians generally say राम् (Raam), while in Tamilnadu they generally say रामा (Raamaa).. neither of which is 100% correct, but it's alright for daily use.

You can see vibhakthis explained here - https://sanskritinstitute.wordpress.com/sanskrit/

Comment: But the rama shabda is अकारान्तः पुन्लिङ्गः राम शब्दः . It is rama word. ISn't it?

Comment: @SreeCharan, Raama is fine. Raam or Raamaa are not. Also, i'm not sure how gramatically correct that sanskrit sentence is. maybe it is just what people say to denote the 'Raama' shabda, than to use it in a sanskrit shloka

Comment: South Indians call रामा (polonged "aa") only to show affection. We generally call Sita Rama. Ayodhya Rama, Dasharatha Rama..Here Rama is just राम.

Comment: South Indians do not say Raamaa. Even they have different names. Telugu people say Raamudu(They end with du). Tamilians end with (Raamar)'r' or (Raaman)'n'. They use a prolonged one when calling some one only.

Comment: @SreeCharan, yes I agree about Telugu variations, and also Ramar and Raman. so i modified it to say TamilNadu. Since OP had doubts about the elongation, I explained the difference for that only

Comment: @SreeCharan अकारान्तः पुन्लिङ्गः राम शब्दः. अ karaa only. राम.

Comment: raamaa has a different meaning. It means a woman, usually a beautiful one.

Comment: @moonstar2001, yes, thats why i said it's not correct male name. People usually don't name their daughters Raamaa, but Ramaa. But most people call their son Ramaha as Raamaa.

Comment: Not to nitpick but ramaa is a proper noun, raamaa is a common noun. correct sambodhana pratha vibhakti form of rAmaH is rAma which does indeed get distorted to Raamaa when speaking.

Comment: @moonstar2001, that IS nitpicking hehe

Comment: But they had to be picked! :-) ramaa is not the feminine equivalent of raama. Nor is raamaa.

Comment: @moonstar2001, what is the feminine equivalent ?

Comment: There isn't one AFAIK.  "rAmA yana capalAkSula pEru; rAmayana bramhamunaku pEru"

Comment: @moonstar2001, if krishnaa is the feminine form of krishna, why is raamaa not the feminine form of raama ? they mean the same too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59483/discussion-between-moonstar2001-and-ram).

Comment: It is not Raamaha, it is Raamah. Visarga is not added with any vowel.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, what do u mean ? In Sanskrit vibhakthi Rama shabda, they say 'Raamaha Raamou Raamaahaa'

Comment: @ram I mean, that visarga is not 'ha' sound. Ramaha sounds as रामह, where as रामः is Ramah,  not Ramaha. रामः sounds as रामह्, not रामह.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, when visarga is at end of a sentence, it should be pronounced as ह, when it is in middle, it is pronounced as ह् . e.g. in Gita first shloka, we should say yuytsavaha, and maamakaah. it is wrong to say yuyutsavah or maamakaaha

Comment: @ram if we pronounce visarga at the end of line as a full Ha, then the Chhandas structure will change. And this change is wrong. For example, if in an Anustup Chhanda  Shloka, there is visarga at the end of each line, then there would be 8+9 syllables in one line, And 8+9 syllables in other also, which is the not the Anustup Chhanda.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, the visarga is not counted as a syllable. It is pronounced for 1/2 matra.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Once the conversation has moved to chat, it's better if we continue discussion in chat.