# If Draupadi (of Mahabharata) was dark skinned why does Krishna call her a fair skinned woman?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, draupadi

> "Vaisampayana continued, 'In that assembly of heroes Vasudeva then
>   spake unto the weeping Draupadi as follows, 'O fair lady, the wives of
>   those with whom thou art angry, shall weep even like thee, beholding
>   their husbands dead on the ground, weltering in blood and their bodies
>   covered with the arrows of Vivatsu!

I don't think by fair he meant "ethical lady". [Arjuna Parva section twelve (12)](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03012.htm)

Comment: Related or probaby Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18497/who-is-krishna-is-it-draupadi-or-an-avatar-of-vishnu

Answer (score 7):

The [Sanskrit Shloka](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs03013.htm) is:

> रॊदिष्यन्ति सत्रियॊ हय एवं येषां करुद्धासि **भामिनि**

Here, the word भामिनि (bhaamini) is translated as fair lady. The word भामिनि (bhaamini) is a general term to address women. It doesn't mean a fair skinned woman.

It may mean glorious woman, brilliant woman, splendid woman, lovely woman, beautiful woman, charming woman, or it can be simply translated as woman or with name of that woman.

The use of this word can be found in many scriptures such as **Ramcharitmanas** ([example 1](https://wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B8:%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1), [example 2](https://wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B8:%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1_6),..) and **Valmiki Ramayan** ([example 1](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga32/sundara_32_frame.htm), [example 2](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga35/sundara_35_frame.htm),..).